# How do I simplify the following slice of a Makefile?

Tags: makefile

Considering the following Makefile:

```
%.o: %.cpp
    $(C) $(CF) -c $< -o $@

Audio/%.o: Audio/%.cpp
    $(C) $(CF) -c $< -o $@

Game/%.o: Game/%.cpp
    $(C) $(CF) -c $< -o $@

Generation/%.o: Generation/%.cpp
    $(C) $(CF) -c $< -o $@

Input/%.o: Input/%.cpp
    $(C) $(CF) -c $< -o $@

Particle/%.o: Particle/%.cpp
    $(C) $(CF) -c $< -o $@

Screen/%.o: Screen/%.cpp
    $(C) $(CF) -c $< -o $@

Utility/%.o: Utility/%.cpp
    $(C) $(CF) -c $< -o $@
```

How can I simplify it so that it only depends on a list of directories, such as:

```
SUBD = Audio/\
 Game/\
 Generation/\
 Input/\
 Particle/\
 Screen/\
 Utility/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of these rules

```
Audio/%.o: Audio/%.cpp
        $(C) $(CF) -c $< -o $@

# etc.
```

are redundant!  Your first pattern rule

```
%.o: %.cpp
        $(C) $(CF) -c $< -o $@
```

already covers them all.

Comment: So my first rule covers all the subdirectories as well? (and sub-sub directories)?

Comment: Yes. If `Audio/a/b/c/something.cpp` exists, then it will use the first rule to make `Audio/a/b/c/something.o` if it needs `Audio/a/b/c/something.o`.